# Earth History Book

Tags: earth-history, paleoclimatology, reference-request

I'm a PhD student studying the (current) climate of the Earth. I'm also quite interested in the history of planet Earth, although I have little academic background in that area. Is there a good textbook on the history of the planet, ideally one that has some focus on the climate?

Comment: Isn't the study of the earth's history and dynamics a prerequistie for studying the earth's climate ? It was so where i studied. If not, let me recommend to attend the introductory lectures into earth's dynamics. A single book (if it exists) will not have enough content for the use case, IMO.

Comment: No. I don't want masses of detail, this is mostly to satisfy my own curiosity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although not exactly a textbook, I would highly recommend you to read Marcia Bjornerud's [Timefulness](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691181202/timefulness) (2018). It goes through all of Earth's history, including the atmosphere. It's short and kind of poetic, but backed by solid science. Her previous book, *Reading the Rocks*, seems somewhat similar (it's subtitle is *The Autobiography of the Earth*), but I did not read it. It was also praised at the time, so it might be worth reading even if it lacks the more recent discoveries (it's from 2005).